# Scraping a specific table on webpage but coming up empty every time

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Apologize for the simple question but this is my first time using StackOverflow.
I am trying to scrape the table within "table class="RankingListGrid" inside the body of the url:

https://www.badmintonplayer.dk/DBF/Ranglister/

The xpath is `//*[@id="PanelResults"]/table`

The selector is `#PanelResults > table`

But regardless of what and which method I try - I come up empty. Having watched a number of instruction videos I am getting a bit desperate. Any suggestion or hint would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Its important to add some code to your question -- the method(s) you've tried so far. (Try to make it a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). That gives us a starting point to see where things are going wrong -- and will lead to more relevant answers.

Comment: Understood - I will try adding some code next time. This was my first post, so still a complete beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Costaparas mentioned it would be great to get a minimal working example --actually it is not clear what you ar working with,...

**Let´s take a look at the following solution / working example:**
Cause the website is loading the `table` and it´s contents dynamically I use `Selenium` and wait in this simple approach that page is loaded with `sleep`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.badmintonplayer.dk/DBF/Ranglister/'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

sleep(3)

table=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PanelResults"]/table').get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(table)

browser.close()
```

**Output:**

```
<tbody><tr><th class="rank sort">Plac.</th><th class="playerid"><a href="#" onclick="return SelectSortField(2);">BadmintonID</a></th><th class="name"><a href="#" onclick="return SelectSortField(3);">Navn</a></th><th class="clas">Række</th><th class="points points">Point</th><th class="points "></th></tr>
<tr><td class="rank">1</td><td class="playerid">940104‑12</td><td class="name"><a href="/DBF/Spiller/VisSpiller/#59158" title="Vis spiller">Viktor Axelsen</a>, Skovshoved</td><td class="clas">SEN E</td><td class="points points">4803</td><td class="points "><a href="/DBF/Spiller/VisSpiller/#59158,287,7489116,2020"><img src="/SportsResults/Images/view-details-red-16.png" title="Vis detaljer"></a></td></tr>
<tr class="alt"><td class="rank">2</td><td class="playerid">940424‑10</td><td class="name"><a href="/DBF/Spiller/VisSpiller/#61161" title="Vis spiller">Robin Tabeling (EU)</a>, Skagen</td><td class="clas">SEN E</td><td class="points points">4714</td><td class="points "><a href="/DBF/Spiller/VisSpiller/#61161,287,7489194,2020"><img src="/SportsResults/Images/view-details-red-16.png" title="Vis detaljer"></a></td></tr>
<tr><td class="rank">3</td><td class="playerid">800711‑01</td><td class="name"><a href="/DBF/Spiller/VisSpiller/#12741" title="Vis spiller">Mathias Boe</a>, Odense OBK</td><td class="clas">SEN E</td><td class="points points">4705</td><td class="points "><a href="/DBF/Spiller/VisSpiller/#12741,287,7480033,2020"><img src="/SportsResults/Images/view-details-red-16.png" title="Vis detaljer"></a></td></tr>
<tr class="alt"><td class="rank">4</td><td class="playerid">920306‑08</td><td class="name"><a href="/DBF/Spiller/VisSpiller/#47081" title="Vis spiller">Kim Astrup Sørensen</a>, Skælskør</td><td class="clas">SEN E</td><td class="points points">4694</td><td class="points "><a href="/DBF/Spiller/VisSpiller/#47081,287,7480403,2020"><img src="/SportsResults/Images/view-details-red-16.png" title="Vis detaljer"></a></td></tr>
...<tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks very promising. As a complete newcomer to StackOverflow (and Python) I will try adding som code next time I post a request.

Comment: Done - sorry for not doing it right away.